# A non-numeric value encountered in phpexel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

Im getting  A non-numeric value encountered in xls file when I use Auto filter ,Im using PHPExel package.
My opertaing system is ubantu 16.04.
Using Libreoffice to view the files.

```
My code
    <?php
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Date');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Invoice');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Client');
    $row = 2;
    foreach ($values['results'] as $value)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row,$columnFilter, date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value->payment_date)));
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$row, $value->invoice_number);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$row, $value->client_name);

        //Problem in below line when I use auto filter Im getting an non numeric value encountered
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:C1');
        $row++;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Cutomer_Report.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');


   Error
   A PHP Error was encountered
   Severity: Warning
   Message: A non-numeric value encountered
   Filename: PHPExcel/Cell.php
   Line Number: 803
```

Comment: post complete error msg

Comment: Do you expect us to guess on what line the error is?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have updated the questions Please take a look.

Comment: @u_mulder I have mentioned on which the error is

Answer (score 3):

Like **voter** said, it's a known bug on the Github and won't be fixed because the developers are focussing on a new library. However, instead of down- and upgrading your environment, you could edit a single line and keep your existing implementation.

As seen in the [Github thread](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1212#issuecomment-300184159):

1. Go to PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php
2. Around line 372, find `$endCoordinates = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($iInc - 1));`
3. Change it to only call the function once: `$endCoordinates = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($iInc - 1);`

Comment: Even in the new library (phpspreadsheet), "A non-numeric value encountered in vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate.php on line 310". This happens in function *stringFromColumnIndex*. I'm always using 'A1' 'A2', etc.. when building my spreadsheets.so I'm unsure why this function is called on my stuff, but it's not my job to debug that. My job is for my stuff to run, so to fix this I changed line 307 in *Coordinate.php*  to *$indexValue = intval($columnIndex);*. I don't like changing vendor stuff but I don't like debugging vendor stuff either. Yes, I used migration.

Answer (score 2):

This is known bug https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1212
To avoid it you can

1. downgrade php
2. upgrade to phpspreadsheet
3. use Excel2007 writer instead of Excel5
4. try to suppress warning with error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING );

Comment: It also happens when using Excel2007.